# NULL Pointer error during executing test scenario in JAVA with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver, testng

I have created some helpers to wrap basic logic in selenium, but I am facing some issue related to null pointer exception. I am checked multiple times with different approaches, but still I can not figure out whats happen. I guess here is problem related to inheritance of classes and providing webdriver from to another and finnally read it in test class. **Here is code: **

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


//@ExtendWith(SeleniumJupiter.class)
public class ElementsHelper extends TestCaseHelper{
    /**
     * Selenium instances for browser.
     */
    private WebDriver driver;
    private WebDriverWait driverWait;
    protected ElementsHelper eH;

    /**
     * Constructor for initialize selenium instances.
     */

    public ElementsHelper(WebDriverWait driverWait, WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        this.driverWait = driverWait;
    }
//    @BeforeClass
//    public void initDriver() {
//        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
//        this.driver = setupChromeDriver();
//        driverWait = setupDriverWait(this.driver);
//    }
    /**
     * Method to check page title
     */
    public String getPageTitle(){
        return driver.getTitle();
    }

    /**
     * Method to get into provided url
     */
    public void goToUrl(String wiki){
        driver.get(wiki);
    }
}
```

```
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import lombok.NonNull;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import org.testng.annotations.*;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public abstract class TestCaseHelper extends TestWithHelpers{
    /**
     * Basic objects used to perform Selenium tests.
     */
    protected WebDriver driver;// = setupChromeDriver();
    protected WebDriverWait driverWait;// = setupDriverWait(driver);;

    /**
     * Test specific params
     */
    protected String browser;
    /**
     * Flag that enables running test on desktop view. [DEFAULT: MOBILE]
     */
    protected Boolean runOnNormalView = Boolean.FALSE;
    /**
     * Default TimmOut for WebDriver actions.
     * Measured in seconds.
     */
    private int TIMEOUT = 75;
    /**
     * Method to call test step message on console during executing.
     */
    protected void testStep(@NonNull String messaege){
        System.out.println("[STEP] " + messaege);
    }
    /**
     * HardCoded Strings
     */
    private String chromeBrowser = "Chrome";
    private String wikiURL = "https://www.google.com";

    public TestCaseHelper(){
        super();
    }
    public TestCaseHelper(WebDriverWait driverWait, WebDriver driver){
        super();
        this.driver = driver;
        this.driverWait = driverWait;
    }
    /**
     * Method to setup Chrome WebDriver.
     */
    protected WebDriver setupChromeDriver(){
//        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
//        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    driver.manage().window().maximize();

                    return driver;
    }
    /**
     * Method to setup DriverWait.
     */
    protected WebDriverWait setupDriverWait(@NonNull WebDriver driver){
        return new WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT);
    }
    /**
     * TestNG lsitener method that runs before each test and sets it up,
     *                                                    creating of WebDriver
     *                                                     and make application ready to web scrapping.
     */
    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters({"Browser"})
    protected void setupBeforeTest(String browser) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        System.out.println("Initialize");
        this.browser = runOnNormalView ? chromeBrowser : browser;
        //for buisness requirments make sure that we are able to use only chrome browser
        if(!browser.equals(chromeBrowser)) throw new ReflectiveOperationException();

        this.driver = setupChromeDriver();
        this.driverWait = setupDriverWait(driver);
    }

    /**
     * TestNg listener method to cleanup after the test.
     */
    @AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)
    protected void cleanUpAfterTest(){
        if(!driver.equals(null)){
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

```
import lombok.Getter;
/**
 * Base class for BuisnessTest to make sure test case can access all app helpers
 */
public abstract class TestWithHelpers {
    protected SearchboxHelper searchboxHelper;
    protected HomePageHelper homePageHelper;
    protected ElementsHelper elementsHelper;
    protected TestCaseHelper testCaseHelper;
}
```

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class BusinessScenarioTest extends TestCaseHelper{
    private String wikiUrl = "https://google.com";
    private String browser = "Chrome";


//    @BeforeTest
//    public void setupBeforeTest(){
//        System.out.println("ESSA");
//    }

    @Test()
    public void runBusinessScenarioTest() throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        //testCaseHelper.setupBeforeTest(browser);

        System.out.println(driver);

        testStep("Go to Selenium tab on Wiki");
        elementsHelper.goToUrl(wikiUrl);

        testStep("Make sure that you are currently on Wiki");
        Assert.assertEquals(elementsHelper.getPageTitle(), wikiUrl);

        testStep("");
    }
}
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR HELP !! <3

Simply get into provided URL.

Comment: Can you add stack trace of the exception? Or tell us which line and which class throws NPE?

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting exception at

```
elementsHelper.goToUrl(wikiUrl);
```

As your inheriting this instance from abstract class TestWithHelpers but this instance is never initialised so it will always be null

```
protected ElementsHelper elementsHelper;
```

You need to Initialise this class instance somewhere for e.g. in your TestCaseHelper class

```
elementsHelper =new ElementsHelper();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the prettiest solution was Reflection class to share instances between classes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).